# How to have int input correlate to a substring?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that takes input from a user. The enter a number 1-12 and it returns the month January-December. I have to have all the months in one long string and then use a substring to return the corresponding month.

I am very confused as to how to get an int to correlate to a substring. I would appreciate some general guidelines for doing this. I'm not looking to have the whole program done for me.

Comment: General guidance: don't do that. Store months in array and live happily thereafter.

Comment: Ok I have to use a substring. Here is the exact problem I am working on.

Comment: Write a program that transforms 1,2,3...12 into the corresponding month January, February... Make a very long string "January February March... " in which you add spaces such that each month name has the same length. Then use substring to extract the month you want.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `substring()`. If you have a csv of month names, use `split()` to turn the string into an array:

```
String months = "January,February,etc";
int choice; // 1-12
String monthName = months.split(",")[choice - 1];
```

Note that java arrays are zero-based, so you must subtract 1 from a 1-12 ranged number when used as an index.

---

Easier to read would be:

```
static String[] monthNames = "January,February,etc".split("");
```

then in your method:

```
String monthName = monthNames[choice - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the values of the month using your substring, store it in your array of String. And then get the 1 - 12 value by their indexes + 1.

Answer (score 0):

Beside using `Split` you can use `StringTokenizer` to parse your string as well.

My Code:

```
    int i = 1;
    int month = 0;
    while (i == 1) {
        System.out.println("Enter your number ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        month = input.nextInt();

        if (month > 13 || month < 0) {
            System.out.println("your number has to be between 1 and 12");
        } else {
            i = 2;
        }
    }

    List<String> monthList = new ArrayList<>();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("January February March April"
            + " May June July August September October November December");

    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        monthList.add(st.nextToken(" "));
    }

    System.out.println("the month is " + monthList.get(month - 1));
```

My Output:

```
Enter your number 
333
your number has to be between 1 and 12
Enter your number 
3
the month is March
```